# How to setup multiple data sources with Spring and JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, jndi, entitymanager

In our application, we want to set multiple data source with Spring and JPA. Hence we have created 2 entityManagerFactory, 2 data source and 2 transaction- manager.

**web.xml**

```
 <param-value>
    /WEB-INF/a_spring.xml
    /WEB-INF/b_spring.xml
 </param-value>
```

**Persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="1.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="db1" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>com.rh.domain.RcA</class>
    </persistence-unit>

      <persistence-unit name="db2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
      <class>com.rh.domain.Rcb</class>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**a_spring.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx" 
           xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.0.xsd
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd">

      <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>  
      <bean id = "RcMaintenanceService" class="com.rh.services.RcAbcMaintenanceServiceImpl" autowire="byName" />

    <aop:config>
            <aop:pointcut id="rOperation" expression="execution(* com.rh.services.*.*(..))"/>
            <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" pointcut-ref="rOperation"/>
        </aop:config>

    <tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager">
            <tx:attributes>
                   <tx:method name="*"/>
            </tx:attributes>
        </tx:advice>

    <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
            <property name="jndiName" value="java:comp/env/jdbc/db1" />
        </bean> 
        <bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
            <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
               <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="db1" />     
            <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"> 
                    <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
                    <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
                    <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
                    <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
                </bean>
            </property>
            <property name="jpaDialect">
                <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect">
                </bean>
            </property>
        </bean>
```

I also declare another entityManagetFactory,Transaction Manager and dataSource to **b_spring.xml**.

**Error**

> Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is
>   defined: expected single bean but found 2 Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   unique bean of type [javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory] is
>   defined: expected single bean but found 2     at
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beanOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:303)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findDefaultEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:451)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findEntityManagerFactory(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:428)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AnnotatedMember.resolveEntityManager(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:582)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AnnotatedMember.resolve(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:553)
>     at
>   org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AnnotatedMember.inject(PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:489)

Comment: Can you post which class is firing the exception, a little bit more of the stack trace could help to troubleshoot this

Comment: @Koitoer I think is because of the configuration problem in Spring Appplication Context

Comment: Is this your complete application context file or it's just a part of it?
Your exception implies that your are injecting your EntityManagerFactory beans by type, while you have to do it by name.

Comment: @ali4j how to do it by name

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace, instead of just the deepest element within it?

Comment: @Hoo..is your problem solved?

Comment: @ali4j no......

Comment: @lusic's answer is clear, Did you try it?

Comment: @ali4j Yes but no luck

Comment: Why do you want to have multiple data sources in 1 application? Are you trying to manage a distributed database level transactions?

Comment: @gumol I need to have multiple database connection

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In case of multiple data source configuration, we need to define which one will be considered as a primary data source. we can specify that using `@Primary` annotation in java config or `primary=true` in XML bean config.

As there is two entity manager being created in XML, we need to use `@Qualifier` to specify which bean should be injected where. In your case, something like this.

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "db1")
public void setEntityManager(@Qualifier("entityManagerFactory") EntityManager entityMgr) {
    this.em = entityMgr;
}
```

for XML configuration, we can do something like this

```
<bean id="BaseService" class="x.y.z.BaseService">
    <property name="em" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    <property name="em1" ref="entityManagerFactory1"/>
</bean>

<bean id = "RcMaintenanceService" class="com.rh.services.RcAbcMaintenanceServiceImpl" autowire="byName" parent="BaseService"/>
```

Comment: cannot find symbol Qualifier

Comment: which version of spring you are using ?

Comment: version: 2.0.5.

Comment: Thanks man, it wasn't directly my problem, but knowing unitName is linked to the EMF bean name..

Answer (score 1):

Did you try providing the package details which contains your EntityManagerFactory bean?

You can provide the package details as a property in you bean definition -

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.XX.XX.XX.XX" />
```

new property to be added in this block -

```
<bean id="entityManagerFactory1" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
           <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="db2" />     
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource1"/>
  <-- add here for both beans  -->

        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"> 
                <property name="showSql" value="true"/>
                <property name="generateDdl" value="false"/>
                <property name="database" value="MYSQL" />
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            </bean>
        </property>
        <property name="jpaDialect">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect">
            </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

Also, you are missing the  `persistenceXmlLocation` property -

```
 <property name="persistenceXmlLocation" value="***/persistence.xml" />
```

Comment: what i mean was add these two missing properties `packagesToScan` and `persistenceXmlLocation` for both entityManagerFactory beans.

Comment: In my case, `packagesToScan = "com.rh.services.RcAbcMaintenanceServiceImpl"` ?

Comment: Invalid `packageToScan` !

Answer (score 1):

The error message you've posted indicates that you're autowiring by type for an object of type EntityManagerFactory. None of the code you've shown so far contains such an injection, which implies that it's probably in some code you haven't yet posted.

If you were to post the full stack trace of the error, you'd be able to walk up the stack to see which bean contains the un-satisfiable reference to an EntityManagerFactory object, which in turn would let you change how you're referencing it to allow a reference to the specific bean you want.

**Update**

Based on the further information you provided (thank you) and some Googling, it seems as though other users have similarly found that specifying a unitName isn't enough to get the correct EntityManager injected. Several posts online back up @lucid's recommendation to use the @Qualifier annotation to get Spring to select the correct bean, but unfortunately [that annotation was introduced in 2.5](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Qualifier.html) so it's only available to you if you upgrade. (Which, given the age of the Spring framework that you're using, is probably a good idea, but that's a separate conversation.)

However, [several users have indicated](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/55951-persistencecontext-jpa-multiple-entitymanagerss) that an alternate approach is available in 2.0.5, using a single PersistenceUnitManager that references multiple data sources rather than multiple persistence units that each reference a single data source. From the official Spring docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.0.x/reference/orm.html#orm-jpa-multiple-pu.

Overall I'd suggest you consider upgrading to a version of Spring that's not more than a decade old, which would let you specify an @Qualifier annotation per @lucid's answer. But if that's not possible for some reason, the PersistenceUnitManager approach should give you a way to make it work within Spring 2.0.5.

Comment: I'm using `org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things that don't look good to me. The name of the setters won't match the property names, I think that is important, the second thing is about the inheritance, some annotations sometimes only works in concrete classes not in base classes. I would try to change the base service as follow.

```
public class BaseService {

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "db2")
private EntityManager em;

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "db1")
private EntityManager em1;

public EntityManager getEm() {
    return em;
}

protected EntityManager getEm2() {
    return em1;
}

public void setEm(EntityManager entityMgr) {
    this.em = entityMgr;
}

public void setEm1(EntityManager entityMgr) {
    this.em = entityMgr;
}
}
```

If that does not work I probably try to remove the base class and see if I put the annotation under the concrete class I can make that works, I would do that moving just the annotations to the `RcAbcMaintenanceServiceImpl` class and remove the extend statement that inherits from the BaseService

Also, I noticed that the `PersistenceContext` annotation has another param https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/PersistenceContext.html, so you could try to use the name as well to match the id on the bean definition.

Comment: Tried your answer but no luck. Will it because `<aop:config>` ?

Comment: Any github link in which I can download the project to see what I can do

Comment: Sorry, it a bit hard to give, there are too many code and structures. The error persist after I declare two entityManagerFactory. Don't know why

Comment: Don't use any bean name that is also the default one used by Spring (like dataSource, transactionManager, entityManager, ...), but suffix them with "1" and "2", there is a little chance that you get an exception somewhere else that will point on the correct place you have to fix.